# Database change is not notified by SignalR

Tags: c#, signalr, sqldependency

I need to notify Web user when a change in the database occurs.

I am using this to register the event:

```
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Security", "CA2100:Review SQL queries for security vulnerabilities")]
    void RegisterForNotifications()
    {
        string connectionString = "";
        using (Repositories.GestionActivosEntities db = new Repositories.GestionActivosEntities())
            connectionString = db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;

        connectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Pooling=False;";
        string sqlQuery = @"SELECT [AlertaId]
                          ,[PadreId]
                          ,[UsuarioOrigenId]
                          ,[UsuarioDestinoId]
                          ,[AlertaOrigen]
                          ,[AlertaNombre]
                          ,[AlertaMensaje]
                          ,[AlertaMotivo]
                          ,[AlertaCreadoEn]
                          ,[AlertaEnviadoMail]
                          ,[AlertaLeidoPortal]
                      FROM [dbo].[Alerta]";

        using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConnection))
        {
            sqlCommand.Notification = null;
            var sqlDependency = new SqlDependency(sqlCommand);
            sqlDependency.OnChange += OnSqlDependencyChange;
            if (sqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                sqlConnection.Open();
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    void OnSqlDependencyChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        {
            SqlNotification?.Invoke(sender, e);
            RegisterForNotifications();
        }
    }
```

When debugging, this code executed correctly, however, when I change a data in that table, OnSqlDependencyChange is not called.

On the other hand, I have a tutorial in this page: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1075852/ASP-NET-MVC-SignalR-SqlDependency-and-EntityFramew?msg=5672753#xx5672753xx

Code I am using is the same as the tutorial. The difference is that I am hardcoding the query and the connection string.

One fact called my attention.

In my code, when the sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); instruction is called, immediately the OnSqlDependencyChange event is called with type "Subscribe". However, in the code in the tutorial, that event is called only when the table has a change. In that case, the event is called with the type "Change".

Database has broker enabled.

What may be going on? Thanks

Comment: Remove SignalR tag as your issue is not reaching that layer at all.

Comment: Is the queue created and SqlDependency **start**ed? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency

Comment: I would expect the lifetime of `sqlDependency` to be longer for this to work..can you scope it somewhere else to try? As soon as the command is executed it is out of scope so I suspect it does not have enough time to respond.

Comment: @ZorgoZ I have this in global.asax: SqlDependency.Start(_connectionString);. I have checled it is being executed.

Comment: @PeterBons what do you mean?

Comment: As soon as `SqlCommand` is disposed (at the end of the using block) the `SqlDependency` is unusable.

Comment: @PeterBons but all examples I have seen so far uses the same piece of code.... and the code from a tutorial, where I copied the code from, has the same and it does work.